# Mysql : Optimal way to do count(*) operation on a low cardinality column

Tags: java, mysql, indexing, aggregate-functions

***Background:***

I have a Mysql schema with the following structure

```
@Data
public class DBQueryEvaluation {
    //primary key
    private final Long id;

    //The combination of a 'query' and an 'evaluationId' will always be unique.
    private final Long evaluationId;
    private final String query;

    private final Date createdAt;
    private final Date updatedAt;
}
```

***Constraint***:

The combination of a *'**query**'* and an *'**evaluationId**'* will always be unique.

There can be quite many queries for a given evaluationId. Total 5 million records in the table. (~ 50,000 queries per evaluationId, with 100's of such evaluations = 5 Million records).

***Goal:***

*Want to do a count(records) for a given evaluationId.*

***Questions:***

Given that *cardinality of evaluationId is quite low* *(same evaluationId repeating for ~50k records)* :

1. Is indexing 'evaluationId' the recommended thing to do here. Expecting the BTree implementation should be able to provide the count in order of milliseconds. (< 10ms)
2. What could be the possible downsides if any for indexing such a low cardinality attribute?
3. What would be the other best approaches to get the count(*).

=== ***Update*** ===

- I am expecting a fully consistent view. No approximations.
- Updates can be applied on top of the existing rows.

Comment: Is the data written once?  Then consider a Data Warehouse-like [_Summary Table_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables)

Comment: @Rick James : Data is written quite frequently.

Comment: Oops, I meant "data is not modified once it is written".

Comment: Np.. it might be modified once written. (Also I am expecting a fully consistent view). Will update the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Is indexing 'evaluationId' the recommended thing to do here. Expecting the BTree implementation should be able to provide the count in order of milliseconds. (< 10ms)

Yes, without the index, the engine has to do a full table scan. Using the index however, it will not have to access the data records, but can get the count from the index alone. To do that it needs to read a number of index records that is much less than the number data records, since:

- Index leaf-blocks have multiple record pointers, which are read in block chunks.
- The number of extra block-reads needed to isolate the leaf-blocks that relate to an evaluation id is logarithmic to the total number of blocks.

For example, if block size is 10, and 50,000 records have the evaluation id, then about 5,555 blocks need to be read. Compare this with at least 500,000 blocks that need to be read in a table scan. Obviously databases have optimisation methods which would complicate a fair comparison, and so it makes sense to just try it.

> 2. What could be the possible downsides if any for indexing such a low cardinality attribute?

The role of the cardinality depends on how many data records fit in one block (i.e. <= recordsize / blocksize). If that number approaches the cardinality, then the benefit of an index will vanish.

> 3. What would be the other best approaches to get the count(*).

You could reassess how important it is to have an *exact* count when such counts are in the order of 50,000, and knowing that the very second after you get the count, there might already have been new insertions/deletions. Does it matter whether it is actually 49,756 and not 49,695?

If an approximation is OK, then run a scheduled batch job that performs the count on all evaluation ids, and stores that in a separate "count" table (which would have about 100 records). Depending on your needs, you would schedule it to run once per day, per hour, ... depending on the turnover and needed accuracy. Then you have lightning speed at the cost of a minor inaccuracy.

To improve accuracy, you could combine the above "count" table with an insert/delete trigger on the data table, that would insert the effect of that change (as a +1 or -1 value) into a log table. Then the query for the number of records would take the "count" table as starting point and modify the result based on those +1/-1 in the log table. The above job would clear the log whenever it runs.

Comment: Thanks @trincot. I was looking for a fully consistent view. Also, would appreciate if you can explain how you arrived at 5,555. The same should be log (base 2) 500000 as per my understanding. '''For example, if block size is 10, and 50,000 records have the evaluation id, then about 5,555 blocks need to be read'''

Comment: How I arrived at 5,555: the log base is whatever the arity is of the B-tree blocks. I looked the at the pyramid (subtree) of blocks in the B-tree that have the leaf blocks that have the searched id. The bottom layer of that pyramid would have 5000 blocks, each with 10 entries (=50,000 record pointers). The parent layer would have 10 times fewer blocks (500), the grandparent level would 50 blocks, ...etc. I ignore the path needed to get to this pyramid as that constitutes only two more levels (= 2 more reads). A "fully consistent view": you see inconsistency?

Comment: Thanks.  By fully consistent view I meant 'no approximation' (In reply to your comment 'Does it matter whether it is actually 49,756 and not 49,695')

Comment: I am curious what the business value is of such strict count requirement. Mostly because that information is outdated immediately. But anyway, then the method in the last paragraphs of my answer would be my advise.

Comment: In my experience, typical arity is 100.